# How to add voiceover accessibility on EditText view when character change in android

Tags: android

```
field1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

   @Override
   public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}

   @Override    
   public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
     int count, int after) {
   }

   @Override    
   public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
     int before, int count) {
      if(s.length() != 0)
        field2.setText("");
   }
  });
```

This is my code where field1 in Edit text view I want to announce voice when onTextchange for each character .
we have a search count variable for each charter
like suppose we enter
**A then  it should tell 10 counts for text A**

**When I enter B then it should tell 4 counts for B** like this for others when 10 and 4 we have a count variable.

default it's telling only Charter when I enter A then it's telling suppose B then it's telling B Enter.

But I want to customize  voice over  accessibility can any one please help me in this Thanks